# How to make RBF with changed output address per CLI?

Tags: bitcoin-cli, replace-by-fee

Please, can anyone explain to me how to make an RBF with changing the output address exactly? Which commands should I use for that? I tried to use the 'send' command to send the same amount with a higher fee, but it says "Insufficient funds." What should I do exactly? I'm using Bitcoin Core 25.0 full node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what I need  `sendall` command do that for more
info about using it exactly look [here](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/25.0.0/rpc/wallet/sendall/)